# Problema de sql de expresiones condicionales

Tags: sql

Apenas estoy comenzando con SQL y estoy atorado en este problema. No se como puedo continuar. Es de expresiones condicionales sobre un problema de personas que tocan instrumentos en duetos en un grupo musical donde todos tocan varios instrumentos.

Tengo que escribir algo que me regrese una tabla con las columnas nombre y guitarra. Las tablas tienen que tener el nombre de las personas y un si o no si es que esas personas tocan la guitarra.

Las tablas con las que trabajo son Estudiantes  y Duetos 
Tabla Estudiantes

```
| id | nombre      |  edad  | sexo
+----+-------------+--------+------
| 1 | Juan         |   23   | M
| 2 | Andrea       |   09   | F
| 3 | Abigail      |   27   | F
| 4 | Simon        |   21   | M
```

Tabla duetos

```
| id |idEstudiante1|idEstudiante2| instrumento
+----+-------------+--------+------
| 20 |    1       |   2     | Piano
| 35 |    2       |   4     | Piano
| 36 |    3       |   2     | Percusiones
| 37 |    4       |   1     | Percusiones
| 35 |    4       |   2     | Guitarra
| 36 |    4       |   2     | Flauta
| 37 |    4       |   3     | Piano
```

Hasta ahora tengo

```
select e.nombre, Coalesce (d.Duetos, '(none)')
from Estudiantes e, Dueto d
where e.id = d.idEstudiante1
and e.id = d.idEstudiante2
and d.instrumento= 'guitarra'
```

Pero esto no regresa nada. Estoy un poco frustrado y no se como puedo continuar. Alguien tiene alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si alguna de estas respuestas ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 1):

Propongo solución con `UNION` e `IF()`:

```
SELECT nombre,
  IF(c1.id IS NULL,'No','Sí') guitarra
  FROM (
    SELECT idEstudiante1 id
      FROM duetos WHERE instrumento='Guitarra'
    UNION
    SELECT idEstudiante2 id
      FROM duetos WHERE instrumento='Guitarra'  
  ) c1 RIGHT JOIN estudiantes e ON c1.id=e.id;
```

Adjunto dataset para las comprobaciones:

```
CREATE TABLE estudiantes(
  id int,
  nombre varchar(31),
  edad float,
  sexo varchar(1)
  );
CREATE TABLE duetos(
  id int,
  idEstudiante1 int,
  idEstudiante2 int,
  instrumento varchar(31)
  );
INSERT INTO estudiantes (id, nombre, edad, sexo) VALUES
  ('1','Juan','23','M'),
  ('2','Andrea','09','F'),
  ('3','Abigail','27','F'),
  ('4','Simon','21','M');
INSERT INTO duetos
  (id, idEstudiante1, idEstudiante2, instrumento) VALUES
  ('20','1','2','Piano'),
  ('35','2','4','Piano'),
  ('36','3','2','Percusiones'),
  ('37','4','1','Percusiones'),
  ('35','4','2','Guitarra'),
  ('36','4','2','Flauta'),
  ('37','4','3','Piano');
```

Answer (score 0):

(La otra respuesta es la que mejor ofrece resultado dado el contexto de la publicación)

- Puedes trabajar con 2 `JOINS` considerando que la llave primaria que tienes para identificar al estudiante la usas tanto para la columna de estudiante 1 como para estudiante2
- Le das un alias a cada `JOIN`
- Haces uso de un `CASE WHEN` para verificar si el valor de la columna de instrumento es igual a guitarra

Consulta

```
SELECT estudiantes.nombre,
SUM(CASE WHEN duetos1.instrumento = "Guitarra" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "Dueto1",
SUM(CASE WHEN duetos2.instrumento = "Guitarra" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "Dueto2"
FROM estudiantes
JOIN duetos AS duetos1 ON estudiantes.id = duetos1.idEstudiante1
JOIN duetos AS duetos2 ON estudiantes.id = duetos2.idEstudiante2
GROUP BY estudiantes.nombre;
```

Comment: Mi sistema no me deja escribir THEN, dice que no es valido. Tampoco lo habia visto antes. Sera que es otra version de SQL la que estoy estudiando?

Comment: Que gestor de bases de datos usas pues sql es el lenguaje @DashSysre

Comment: La verdad no se... es de mi clase de bases de datos nos da un sistemita online donde podemos jugar con las bases de datos que nos dan. Solo nos dijeron que es SQL pero la verdad no se que versiones existan o que haya cambiado. Con lo que escribiste estoy muy cerca! 

Me regresa una tabla con 3 columnas. Nombres Y dueto1 y dueto 2. Efectivamente en la posicion del nombre en dueto 1 aparece un 1 y tambien en la otra. Pero como puedo unirlas estas en una sola tabla para que solo pueda tener 2 columnas en lugar de 3?